# Show that $T$ is complex differentiable if and only if $B = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $T:\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{C}$ be a real linear map. Show that $T$ can be written $\begin{aligned}Tz&=Az+B\bar{z}\end{aligned}$ for unique $A,B\in\mathbb{C}.$ Show that $T$ is complex differentiable if and only if $B = 0$.

Here's what I tried:
applying linearity of $T$: $$T(x+iy)=Tz=T(x)+yT(i)$$
$$Tz=Az+B\bar{z}=Ax+iBy$$
We get $A=\frac{T(x)}x$ for $x\neq0$, and $B=\frac{T(y)}{iy}$ for $y\neq0.$
Is this correct so far? I don't really know how to proceed further.

Comment: The fact that $T$ is real linear means that we don't necessarily have $T(iy) = iT(y)$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Why doesn't it hold? Is there any other property that I should use here by chance?

Comment: "Real-linear" means that we have $T(\alpha z) = \alpha T(z)$ for all real numbers $\alpha$, but $i$ is not a real number so this property does not apply.

Comment: You could write $T(iy) = yT(i)$, though.

Comment: Be careful.  You seem to have written $z=x$ and $\bar{z} = iy$ in your work.  That's not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the real-linearity of $T$, we can write that for $x,y \in \Bbb R$ we have
$$
T(x + iy)  = x(1) + yT(i) = Px + Qy,
$$
where $P = T(1)$ and $Q = T(i)$ are complex numbers. Taking $z = x + iy$, we can use the fact that $x = \frac 12 (z + \bar z)$ and $y = \frac 12 (z - \bar z)$ to write
$$
T(z) = P\cdot \frac 12(z + \bar z) + Q \cdot \frac 1{2i} (z - \bar z) = \frac{P - Qi}{2}z + \frac{P + Qi}{2}\bar z.
$$
So, taking $A = \frac{P - Qi}{2}$ and $B = \frac{P + Qi}{2}$, we indeed have $T(z) = Az + B \bar z$.

Now, apply the Cauchy Riemann equations to $T$ to conclude that $T$ is complex differentiable if and only if $\text{Re}[P] = -\text{Im}[Q]$ and $\text{Im}[P] = \text{Re}[Q]$, which is to say that $B = 0$.

Alternatively, for a more direct approach, it suffices to consider the derivative of this map at $z = 0$. We find the limit
$$
\lim_{\Delta z \to 0}\frac{T(\Delta z) - T(0)}{\Delta z} = \lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{T(\Delta z)}{\Delta z}.
$$
Taking the limit along the real axis gives us the result $P$, whereas taking this limit along the imaginary axis gives us the result $Q/i$. These limits must be equal in order for the limit to exist, hence we get $P = Q/i$ and thus $B = 0$.

An alternative, elaborating on Kroki's approach: suppose that $B$ is non-zero and for the purpose of contradiction suppose that $T$ is differentiable. The function $z \mapsto \bar z$ can be written as $\frac 1B(T - f)$, where $f(z) = Az$. Because $f$ and $T$ are differentiable, it would follow that $z \mapsto \bar z$ is differentiable, which is false. The conclusion follows.

Comment: $y = (z - \overline{z}) / (2i)$

Comment: @Kroki That was a bad mistake, thank you

Answer (score 1):

$T(z) = x T(1) + y T(i) = \frac12 \left(T(1) \left(z + \overline{z}\right) -i T(i)\left(z - \overline{z}\right)\right) = \frac12\left(T(1) - iT(i)\right)z + \frac12 \left(T(1) + iT(i)\right) \overline{z}$

For the second part use the fact that $z\mapsto \overline z$ is not a complex differentiable.